# data collection with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array.

```
var data = [
  {
    'key': "Parent A",
    'value': [{
      'key': "Child A.1",
      'value': "A1"
    }]
  },
  {
    'key': "Parent B",
    'value': [{
        'key': "Child B.1",
        'value': "B1"
      },
      {
        'key': "Child B.2",
        'value': "B2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to create a new array where the child element will be in one line.

For example,

```
{ info: 'outside = (Parent B) inside(Child B.1 , Child B.2)' }
```

I have tried the following code

```
var newData = []
data.forEach(function(elements) {
  var elOne = elements.value

  for (var childElement = 0; childElement < elOne.length; childElement++) {
    var r = elOne[childElement].key
    newData.push({
      'info': "outside = (" + elements.key + ") inside(" + r + ")"
    })
  }
})

console.log("--------------------")
newData.forEach(yy=> console.log(yy))
```

The result is  this

```
{ info: 'outside = (Parent A) inside(Child A.1)' }
{ info: 'outside = (Parent B) inside(Child B.1)' }
{ info: 'outside = (Parent B) inside(Child B.2)' }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your required output instead of some complex representations?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I think that actually is the required output format, judging by the code structure.

Comment: { info: 'outside = (Parent B) inside(Child B.1 , Child B.2)' }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you don't want to do a new "push" for every childElement, instead you want to concatenate all the child elements into a string and do one "push" per parent element containing the concatenated string:

```js
var data = [

  {
    'key': "Parent A",
    'value': [{
      'key': "Child A.1",
      'value': "A1"
    }]
  },
  {
    'key': "Parent B",
    'value': [{
        'key': "Child B.1",
        'value': "B1"
      },
      {
        'key': "Child B.2",
        'value': "B2"
      }
    ]
  }
];
var newData = [];
data.forEach(function(elements) {
  var elOne = elements.value;
  var r = "";
  for (var childElement = 0; childElement < elOne.length; childElement++) {
    if (r != "") r += ", ";
    r += elOne[childElement].key;
  }
  newData.push({
    'info': "outside = (" + elements.key + ") inside(" + r + ")"
  })

})

console.log("--------------------")
newData.forEach(yy => console.log(yy))
```

Comment: @myCode Please mark this as the correct answer then

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```js
const newData = [];
const data = [
        {
                'key' : "Parent A",
                'value' : [ { 'key' : "Child A.1", 'value' : "A1" } ]
        },
        {
                'key' : "Parent B",
                'value' : [ { 'key' : "Child B.1", 'value' : "B1" }, { 'key' : "Child B.2", 'value' : "B2" } ]
        }
];

data.forEach((elem) => {
 const child = elem.value.map((o) => o.key).join(' , ');
 newData.push({ info: `outside = (${elem.key}) inside(${child})` });
});

console.log(newData);
```

Here, I iterate on the `data` array, I get all keys from the `value` property with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) function and, finally, I concate them with [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join).